# Find if a row contain a character and create a new column to label data

Tags: r

Having a dataframe with one column and every check in every row if "#" exist in text like these data:

```
"https://example.com/test-ability/321#321"
"https://example.com/test-ability/"
"anothertext#"
"notwithwhatyousearch"
```

How is it possible to find if every row contains the character "#" and create a second new column and label the row which have this character with "A" and row which has not the character with "B"?
Example of expected out

```
"https://example.com/test-ability/321#321", "A"
    "https://example.com/test-ability/", "B"
    "anothertext#", "A"
    "notwithwhatyousearch", "B"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(x = c("https://example.com/test-ability/321#321",
                      "https://example.com/test-ability/",
                      "anothertext#",
                      "notwithwhatyousearch"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(grepl("#", x), "A", "B"))

#                                          x flag
# 1 https://example.com/test-ability/321#321    A
# 2        https://example.com/test-ability/    B
# 3                             anothertext#    A
# 4                     notwithwhatyousearch    B
```

Or a base R solution:

```
df$flag = ifelse(grepl("#", df$x), "A", "B")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this Python code, I don't know much about R language may be this will help you as reference:

```
ls=["https://example.com/test-ability/321#321",
"https://example.com/test-ability/",
"anothertext#",
"notwithwhatyousearch"]          #Creating Data Frame

length=len(ls)                   #Finding list length
for i in range(0, length):       #Iteration
    if('#' in ls[i]):
        print(ls[i],' A')
    else:
        print(ls[i],' B')
```